# Tooltip showing in wrong position after animation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have that drawer that can be resized by clicking on a button, that button have a description via tooltip.

Currently, when the button is clicked the tooltip stays in the old position and does not adjust to new position of the button

Here are screenshots

Before the button is clicked :

[image: before button click]

After the button is clicked :

[image: After button click]

I want the tooltip to either follow the button's new position or to hide and not stay in the middle of screen.

I tried many solutions like hiding the tooltip via onClick but its not working I need an event after the animation finishes.

Here is my code

Sidebar

```
import {CSSObject, styled, Theme} from "@mui/material/styles";
import MuiDrawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import React from "react";

const drawerWidth = 260;

const openedMixin = (theme: Theme): CSSObject => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: 'hidden',
});

const closedMixin = (theme: Theme): CSSObject => ({
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
    },
});

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, {shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open'})(
    ({theme, open}) => ({
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0,
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        ...(open && {
            ...openedMixin(theme),
            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
        }),
        ...(!open && {
            ...closedMixin(theme),
            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
        }),
    }),
);

type Props = {
    open: boolean,
    children: any
}
const Sidebar = ({open, children}: Props) => {
    return (
        <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open} PaperProps={{elevation: 2}}>
            {children}
        </Drawer>
    )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

SidebarFooter :

```
            <CustomTooltip title={open ? 'hide' : 'show'}>
                <div className={iconStyle}>
                    <IconButton onClick={toggleDrawer}>
                        {open ? <ChevronLeftIcon/> : <ChevronRightIcon/>}
                    </IconButton>
                </div>
            </CustomTooltip>
```

CustomTooltip

```
import {Tooltip} from "@mui/material";


type Props = {
    title: string,
    placement?: 'bottom-end'
        | 'bottom-start'
        | 'bottom'
        | 'left-end'
        | 'left-start'
        | 'left'
        | 'right-end'
        | 'right-start'
        | 'right'
        | 'top-end'
        | 'top-start'
        | 'top',
    hide?: boolean,
    children: any
}
const CustomTooltip = ({title, children, placement = 'right', hide = false}: Props) => {
    if (hide) {
        title = ''
    }

    return (
        <Tooltip arrow title={title} placement={placement}>
            {children}
        </Tooltip>
    )
}

export default CustomTooltip;
```

Comment: can you show your html and css ?

Comment: provide code in code sandbox so we can debug it

Comment: your problem is related to MUI Tooltip using [react portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) and this tooltip element is not in the button.

you can use placement="left" for example

Comment: Even with placement=left I still have the same issue, the tooltip will never follow the drawer nor hide but show up near the mouse and stay blocked unless I click outside

Comment: yes, your tooltip render in the body tag (in the react portal)
may be you can place tooltip in the button parent ?